# Angular2 - Service initial call is null

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I have a parent component with children routes. What I'm trying to do is share a project variable between them. The project value can change, and when it changes i need to update all the route pages. I have been following the [anuglar2 tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service) on how to achieve this. However, i get a problem when i first install call my observable. When i call it the first time, the value does not display, however, when i update it, the value then displays. I have not been able to figure out why the project variable initially does not have a value. Anyone know why this is and how to fix it?

**parent route** (Where project can be set and updated )

```
onSubmit(value: any, valid: any) {
    if (valid) {
        // http request to get project 
        this.ad.searchProject(value)
            .subscribe(
            response => {
                // If projet found set value in service 
                this.ad.setProject(response);
                // navigate to child rotue 
                this.router.navigate(['./project'], { relativeTo: this.route });
            },
            error => {
                console.log(error)
            },
            () => {
                console.log("Project Loaded");
            }
            );
    }
}
```

**project service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class ProjectService {
    public project: Project;
    // Observable string sources
    private projectSource = new Subject<Project>();
    // Observable string streams
    projectListener$ = this.projectSource.asObservable();
    constructor(private http: Http) {
    }
    searchProject(value: string): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.post('/controller/Project/SearchProject', { value: value }, { headers: headers })
            .map(response => response.json());
    }
    // Service message commands
    setProject(project: Project) {
        this.projectSource.next(project);
        console.log("call setProject"); 
    }
}
```

**child route**

```
export class ChildComponent {
    project: Project = null;
    subscription: Subscription;
    constructor(private ad: ProjectService) {
        console.log("call child route"); 
        this.subscription = this.ad.projectListener$.subscribe(
            value => {
                // Called after second value is entered
                console.log("call subscription");
                console.log(value);
                this.project = value;
            });
    }
}
```

console.log

```
[HMR] connected
call parent route
Gravity_Project
setProject
Project Loaded
call child route
// done with first project entry 
Waves Project
call subscription
Object {id: 1001, typeID: 45004, studentID: 10000…}
call setProject
Project Loaded
// done with second project entry
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is Behavior Subject (https://hassantariqblog.wordpress.com/2016/12/03/angular2-difference-between-a-behavior-subject-and-an-observable/)

“Behavior Subject is a type of subject, a subject is a special type of observable so you can subscribe to messages like any other observable. The unique features of a behavior subject are:

Behavior subject needs an initial value as it must always return a value on subscription even if it hasn’t received a next()
Upon subscription, it returns the last value of the subject. A regular observable only triggers when it receives a onnext
at any point you can retrieve the last value of the subject in a non-observable code using the getValue() method.

Comment: I am glad to help